# How to set symlink short cut to Sublime Text 3 in terminal?

Tags: zsh, symbolic-link, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

I'm using the ZSH bash https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

I found and followed the directions here to symlink Sublime Text 3 to `subl`
https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html

> The first task is to make a symlink to subl. Assuming you've placed
>   Sublime Text in the Applications folder, and that you have a ~/bin
>   directory in your path, you can run:
>
> ```
> ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
> ```

First I had an error, not `bin` folder in my user directory, so I went ahead and created an empty one, then the command worked.

However I got this error: `zsh: command not found: subl`

I also added the export path into my .zshrc file
`export EDITOR='subl -w'`

And I still get that error :(

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer, I had to *first* change dir to `/usr/local/bin`

Then run:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" subl
```

(For Sublime text 3)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889484/command-subl-from-terminal-dont-work